# Saving a polygon object into a bitmapimage in WIndows phone 8.1

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app where I need to convert a polygon object to an image and ultimately save it as a png file. Till now, I created a polygon object with various properties. Now I'm clueless about the other parts.

```
        pol.Opacity = 0.5;
        System.Windows.Point Point1 = new System.Windows.Point(10, 200);
        System.Windows.Point Point2 = new System.Windows.Point(60, 140);
        System.Windows.Point Point3 = new System.Windows.Point(130, 140);
        System.Windows.Point Point4 = new System.Windows.Point(180, 200);
        System.Windows.Point Point5 = new System.Windows.Point(130, 260);
        System.Windows.Point Point6 = new System.Windows.Point(60, 260);
        PointCollection myPointCollection = new PointCollection();
        myPointCollection.Add(Point1);
        myPointCollection.Add(Point2);
        myPointCollection.Add(Point3);
        myPointCollection.Add(Point4);
        myPointCollection.Add(Point5);
        myPointCollection.Add(Point6);
        pol.Points = myPointCollection;
        var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
        pol.Fill = imageBrush;
        pol.Height = image.Height;
        pol.MaxHeight = image.Height;
        pol.MaxWidth = image.Width;
        pol.Width = image.Width;
        pol.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        pol.StrokeThickness = 2;
        pol.Margin = image.Margin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WritableBitmap class in order to achieve this. I have a similar post on Silverlight, which you can refer: [How to Crop an Image based on a Shape or Path control?](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/12/how-to-crop-image-based-on-shape-or-path.html#Y4iUFRi2yDfiAI7V.99). Hope that helps, at least gives some basic concepts. Let me know, if you need further help on this.

Comment: Exactly... I have been using the same too.

Comment: It worked actually but the new problem that I'm facing is saving the shape as a png file in "photos" of WIndows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

To save the shape as PNG, you can utilize the following code snippet:

```
       WriteableBitmap bmp = GetAsWritableBitmap();
       using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
       {
           using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               var fileName = string.Format("Gs{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
               bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
               stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
               var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
               if (picture.Name.Contains(fileName)) return true;
           }
       }
```

Hope that helps.